OAuth2 authtentication and proxy connection
I’m using the alexa-remote2 class to develop a Homey app that can interact with Amazon Echo devices but I'm having problems getting the authentication cookie from inside the app.
This class uses a proxy for authentication and login cookie retrieval. If I use the class on the Desktop PC I have no problems and I can retrieve the json with all the login cookie data (and if I manually import the json in my Homey app everything works fine).
However, I have many problems authenticating from Homey: inside the Homey app (to be precise inside the OAuth2Client class) the IP address and port that I set for the proxy connection do not work (the browser opens but gives the error that the address does not exist).
For authentication I’m using the Homey OAuth2 class.
Has anyone had experience using a proxy for authentication in a Homey app?
Thanks,
Simone
